# How to remove brackets [ ] from List when going to display as a String and add it to a text element for display using Flutter

Tags: flutter, desktop-application, flutter-desktop

I want to go through my List of Strings, and add it to a text element for display, but I want to remove the []. I am using multiselect: ^0.0.4 package.

If the List is.

**['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']**

I want to show in the text as - **S,M**

CODE :-

```
List<String> selected = [];

  child: DropDownMultiSelect(
    onChanged: (List<String> x) {
      setState(() {
        selected = x;
      });
    },
    options: ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'],
    selectedValues: selected,
    whenEmpty: 'Select Size',
  ),

DataCell(Text(
  '$selected ',
  style: const TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 25.0,
  ),
)),
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy:

```
selected.join(',');
```